# Как в Sphinx сделать 'like' условие?

Tags: sphinx

К примеру есть столбец date:

1. 2017-11-04
2. 2017-11-17
3. 2017-11-17
4. 2017-01-01
5. 2020-11-04

Нужно получить все даты "11-04" всех лет, или же грубо говоря с условием LIKE "%-11-04"

Answer (score 1):

В Sphinx нет LIKE для string attributes, так что через строки никак. Если date типа timestamp, то вот так можно:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select *, month(date) m, day(date) d from t where m=11 and d=4;
+---------------------+------------+------+------+------+
| id                  | date       | f    | m    | d    |
+---------------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 1657843905795719185 | 1509793200 |      |   11 |    4 |
| 1657843905795719189 | 1604487600 |      |   11 |    4 |
+---------------------+------------+------+------+------+
```

В Manticore Search (open-source продолжении Сфинкса) есть REGEX(), так что там можно и со строками. Вот пример:

```
MySQL [(none)]> create table t(f text, date string);
MySQL [(none)]> insert into t(date) values('2017-11-04') , ('2017-11-17'), ('2017-11-17'), ('2017-01-01'), ('2020-11-04');
MySQL [(none)]> select date, REGEX(date, '11-04') t FROM t where t = 1;
+------------+------+
| date       | t    |
+------------+------+
| 2017-11-04 |    1 |
| 2020-11-04 |    1 |
+------------+------+
```